# Problema com insercao de datas em php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho uma tabela de **emprestimos** com os campos **data_emprestimo** e **data_prazo**, quero poder fazer a insercao da data actual na tabela **data_emprestimo** e uma data de limite na tabela **data_prazo** adicionando 7 dias da **data_emprestimo**.

Comment: Tenho uma tabela de **emprestimos** com os campos **data_emprestimo** e **data_prazo**, quero poder fazer a insercao da data actual na tabela **data_emprestimo** e uma data de limite na tabela **data_prazo** adicionando 7 dias da **data_emprestimo**.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar as seguintes funções [`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) e [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), combinando-as você faria:

**SELECT**

```
SELECT NOW() AS data_emprestimo, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS data_prazo;
```

**INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO emprestimos (data_emprestimo, data_prazo) VALUES (NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

@edit

Caso procure uma solução diretamente no `PHP`, você pode utilizar as funções [`date`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) e [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php):

```
$data_emprestimo = date('d/m/Y');
$data_prazo = date($data_emprestimo, strtotime("+7 days"));
```

Comment: Usei esse metodo: $empretimo->createEmp(array(
        'data_emprestimo' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'data_limite' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days")),
        'estado' => 'activo'
    ), "emprestimo");

Comment: Você não especificou em qual linguagem deveria ser a solução (`PHP` ou `MySQL`), acrescentei uma outra resposta.